# Safari not downloading base64 image

Tags: javascript, ios, html, image, base64

When using [this demo](http://zipso.net/sketchpad/sketchpad-saveimage.html) the image saves just fine on chrome when I hit save image but it just shows a weird box on safari(iPad). When I hold the image and hit save it doesn't do anything at all. How can I fix this?

**Edit:** apparently someone thought the problem was resolved, it's not. Any suggestions are still welcome! :D

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry about that.

Comment: how did you fix it?

Comment: I never did unfortunately